# central server shell that runs multiple remote server shells and waits for the results

Tags: shell-script

I made a server control shell that works as below

1. Run master shell on central server.
2. Master shell asynchronously calls remote shells on standby servers.
3. Each standby server shells writes '**SERVER xxx DONE**' on the same result file on central server.
4. Meanwhile the Master Shell periodically reads the result file until every server writes '**DONE**'.
5. Maste shell then switches load balance.

---

But I don't think writing on a file and loop parsing it isn't ideal way of communication.

The biggest problem of my shell is that master shell will wait forever if any remote shell fails to write '**DONE**' for whatever reason.

---

### ENV

The systems are Centos7 and master shell is run on `bash`. Master runs each server shells that restart `tomcat`s and wait until fully booted. If specific port is up, remote shells modifies the result file that the master shell is reading through `ssh` command. But I don't like how servers are exchanging information through `awk` and `grep`. I thought there should be a better way.

---

### Question

1. In a situation where master shell executes multiple remote shells on a background, what is the best way to exchange result data?
2. In above workflow, how can I make the master shell to run step #5 only when step #4 is successful, without making it waiting indefinitely? I want to avoid normal servers having to do startup all over again.

---

### Edit

After Master Shell execute remote shells it runs a while loop with server names.

The result file looks like this,

```
server1 RUNNING
server2 RUNNING
server3 RUNNING
```

Master shell greps `server1`, `server2`, `server3` and check if the status is `RUNNING`, `FAILED` or `DONE`.

If it greps `DONE`, the shell removes that server from the loop.

Remote shells simply `awk` `RUNNING` to `DONE` when tomcat is normally booted.

Comment: You can't wait for step 4 to be successful if in the next breath you're saying don't wait undefinitely. Something has to give way. Either some part of step 4 must fail or time out and so you continue knowing that not all of step 4 is complete, or you guarantee that step 4 can never return anything except success, or you have to wait indefinitely

Comment: @roaima, I disagree that this question should be closed. The OP doesn't explicitly mention he's using Unix/Linux, and he should definitely add more details such as the OS he's using, and how exactly he's running this automation, but I think it's a perfectly valid question.

Comment: Please add additional information: What is your OS, how do you perform the remote shell (I assume `ssh`?), what's the command you run on the remote servers (I assume you run a command, and not just interactive shell), and how is it related to load balancing. Except for the remote servers writing "DONE" on some file (BTW, how? Via NFS?), is there any other information the server needs to get from the clients? What's the goal of this solution?

Comment: @aviro The systems are Centos7 and master shell is run on bash. Master runs each server shells that restart tomcats and wait until fully booted. If specific port is up, remote shells modifies the result file that the master shell is reading through ssh command. But I don't like how servers are exchanging information through awk and grep. I thought their should be a better way.

Comment: @Lunartist that comment is going to get missed oh so easily. Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/694588/edit) to include information as if you'd provided it in the first place

Comment: Even after you edited the question, I'm still not sure what kind of "information" the servers exchange. The only information you wrote, is that the servers write "DONE" to some centeral file after the `tomcat` is successfully restarted. Your question is still not clear enough, please edit it once more to clarify what kind of additional information the servers exchange, and where `grep` and `awk` are used. In addition, when you say that "*master shell is run on `bash`*", I assume a `bash` **script**, and not an interactive `shell`. If so, maybe show the exact script (or command) you're running?